# "Attributes specified for column are incompatible with existing column definition"

Tags: db2

It's been a while.

Using DB2 10 for z/OS, I've been asked to change a specific column in a table from decimal(7,2) to decimal(7,4). Sounds easy, right?

```
alter table MySchema.MyTable
alter column myColumn
set data type decimal(7,4);
```

But, DB2 responds with this error: "Attributes specified for column 'MYCOLUMN' are incompatible with existing column definition."

I had thought that converting from decimal(7,2) to decimal(7,4) would be pretty straightforward, but DB2 disagrees.

Outside of dropping the table and recreating it from scratch, what alternatives do I have?

Thanks in advance!

Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new column `ALTER ADD COLUMN` of the right type, use an `UPDATE` to populate it, `ALTER DROP COLUMN` the old column. `RENAME COLUMN` so set the name of the original column.

Answer (score 2):

The reason Db2 doesn't like that change is you're going from from 99999.99  to 999.9999

Is that really what you want?  Going from (7,2) to (9,4) would just add two more decimal places without losing any data and should be allowed by the Db.

Db2 for i gives a warning, but allows you to ignore the warning...

Comment: I miss DB2 for i. Things were so much easier then.